# Vector slicing in C++ in recursion

Tags: python, c++, list, recursion, vector

Here is a simple function to print a list in reverse using python.

```
def print_list(lst):
    if not lst:
        return
    print_list(lst[1:])  # How to achieve this slicing in C++ vector without any global, static variable.
    print(lst[0], end=" ")
```

I have to rewrite this function in C++ without modifying the function prototype as well as I don't want to use the static/global index variables.

> C++ function prototype and Pseudocode.

```
void print_rev(vector<int> &vec) {
    if(it reaches vector end)
        return;
    print_rev(vec[1:])
    print(vector elements during stack unwinding phase)
}
```

How to slice the vector like in the python function?

Comment: If you have to keep that signature, you're asking for a local copy of a vector to be made in every recursive call. In c++20, you can use `std::span`. That'll be efficient, and the syntax is easy.

Comment: Python is not C++.  You solve the C++ issue using C++ paradigms and idioms, and forget python exists.  This goes for any language -- you don't write code in one language using another language as a model.

Comment: "Rewrite without modifying the function signature" doesn't mean that you have to implement this with recursion.  Simply using a reverse iterator would do the job just fine.  Unrelated, but defining this function with a non-const reference parameter when the function clearly should not be modifying the vector is generally considered bad style in C++.

Answer (score 0):

> I have to rewrite this function in C++ without modifying the function prototype as well as I don't want to use the static/global index variables.

If the sole purpose of the function is to write it in reverse, you can use `std::vector::reverse_iterator`. You don't need modify the input object or create temporary ones in a recursive call.

```
void print_rev(vector<int> &vec)
{
    for ( auto iter = vec.rbegin(); iter != vec.rend(); ++iter )
    {
        print(*iter);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Personally I would not use recursion to do this and use a reverse iterator instead like in the answer given by @r-sahu. However, if you really want to do it using recursion then it is possible with another overload of `print_rev()` that takes iterators. This would avoid having to create a new temporary vector with each call of `print_rev()`:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

using Iter = std::vector<int>::iterator;

void print_rev(Iter start, Iter end)
{
    if (start == end)
        return;
    print_rev(std::next(start), end);
    std::cout << *start;
}

void print_rev(std::vector<int> &vec) {
    print_rev(vec.begin(), vec.end());
}

int main() {
    std::vector<int> v = {1,2,3,4,5};
    print_rev(v);   
}
```

Output:

```
54321
```

Here's a [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/bPc3cG).